# Why does including a .js file in an MVC3 partial view cause issues with jQuery "active" variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, automation, partial

Our test team came across an issue with their automation scripts using WebDriver. They were using a wait for $.active == 0 to determine that all ajax requests had finished before proceeding. However, with certain partial view loads, the active variable was not decrementing, thereby making the automation very difficult.

I investigated and found that the issue only arose when partial views were being loaded that had an include of a .js file and were loaded via an ajax call. However, it did not happen for all views that included a file. This is how we were including the additional js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Script("Internal/People/CommitteeMembership.js")" />
```

The problem views had one common issue. The script include was defined near the top of the partial view. When I moved this down to the bottom of the partial view, the issue went away and the $.active variable correctly decrements and ends up at 0 after the ajax call to get the partial view.

**My question is**, can anyone explain why this is happening? I have found no instructions to put the js includes at the bottom of the partial view anywhere? At the least the problem is fixed and our automation tests can continue, but I would really like to know the why...

Comment: Do you also use a masterpage? because if you do you can just include the scripts in your masterpage and there is no need to put it in your partial view too. if you already do that you are including it twice which might solve the whole problem you are having right now :)

Answer (score 0):

This has strictly nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET MVC usually spits HTML. This HTML contains markup and in your case javascript. So if you are saying that the position of the javascript inclusion makes a difference, that's because that's how your scripts are organized and dependent between them.

Personally I tend to include all javascript towards the end of the lmarkup, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There isn't really any dependency with other scripts. There is only one js include. The js file simply had a function that gets called on click of some element. I never had an error with this code, the issue is that the internal jQuery variable, "active", is not decrementing after the ajax call to load the view. Nowhere in our application is there code to alter this variable so I don't see why the position of one js file include should have any bearing on a internal jQuery variable.